# Convert Date from MMM dd yyy to dd/mm/yyyy and vice versa

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, material-ui

I am using a native material-ui date picker which by default displays dates in the `dd/mm/yyy` format.  I need to be able to display dates like this: `Jun 18 2012 12:00AM`.  That is how dates are stored in my database and it cannot be changed for continuity.  After pulling from the database, all other information is populated into textFields and Select boxes, but the date fields are left empty.  Picking a date works just fine with no errors.  Is it possible to convert `Jun 18 2021` into `18/06/2012` and then the opposite when pushing back to the database?

```
if (row?.FieldType === "Date") {
    return (
        <TextField
            type="date"
            value={row?.Value || null}
            onChange={(e) => {
                setDetails((prev) => {
                    const update = [...prev.fields];
                    update[index] = {
                        ...update[index],
                        Value: e.target.value,
                    };
                return { ...prev, fields: update };
                });
            }}
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            label={row["FieldName"]}
            InputLabelProps={{
                shrink: true,
            }}
        />
    );
}
```

This is how I am getting my data:

```
const [details, setDetails] = useState("");
    const fetchDetails = async () => {
        setBusy(true);
        setDetails(await fetch(`/fiscalyears/FY2023/intakes/${params.id}/details`).then((response) => response.json()));
        setBusy(false);
};
```

This is how I determine which data is a Select, textField, or Date:

```
<Box>
    {details["fields"]?.map((row, index) => {
        if (row?.FieldType === "Text" || row?.FieldType === "Decimal" || row?.FieldType === "Number") {
            return (
                <TextField value={dateInNumbers || ""} />
            );
        }
        if (row?.FieldType === "Date") {
            return (
                <TextFieldtype="date"
                    format="MMM/dd/yyyy"
                    value={row?.Value || null}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                        setDetails((prev) => {
                            const update = [...prev.fields];
                            update[index] = {...update[index],
                                Value: e.target.value,
                            };
                            return { ...prev, fields: update };
                        });
                    }}
                    InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true, }}
                />);
                                } else {
                                    return (
                                        <TextField
                                            value={row?.Value || ""}
                                            variant="outlined"
                                            margin="normal"
                                            select
                                        >
                                            {row?.Choices.map((choice) => (
                                                <MenuItem key={choice} value={choice}>
                                                    {choice}
                                                </MenuItem>
                                            ))}
                                        </TextField>
                                    );
                                }
                            })}
                        </Box>
```

Comment: You can use the `Date` object to parse original date string and generate new one when the input is changed. Note however that it might be browser dependent, but using native date picker has the same caveat too. You can use this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/native-date-picker-lpyrhh?file=/demo.tsx) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this...

```js
    const inputDate = "Jun 18 2021";

    const outputDate = new Date(Date.parse(inputDate)).toLocaleString("en-GB"); 
  
    console.log(outputDate.slice(0, 10));
```

**output**: 18/06/2021

Comment: Why not use a code snippet to make the code runnable on screen?

Comment: ``console.log(outputDate.slice(0, 10));`` results in this being logged in the console:  ``Invalid Da``.